# Do comments intentionally eat some emoticons?

Tags: discussion

I just received a reply from a user after commenting that they may have forgotten to use Option Strict On - in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020278/1115360).

Their reply was `maybe... (-_-)` (the emoticon denotes "shame", and the user immediately updated their answer). In the Recent inbox messages dropdown it shows correctly, but there is no sign of the emoticon in the comment.

Is there a reason the emoticon was omitted?

Comment: The comment was edited (you can tell by the pencil next to the timestamp of the comment). AFAIK, inbox messages are stored separate to the comment, *but* when a comment is edited, the "inbox version" of the comment isn't updated.

Comment: @Matt Thank you for that information. Would it be worth putting in a feature request for the "inbox version" to be updated if the comment is edited?

Comment: I'd wait for someone to confirm that what I said is correct first... but then, yes... by all means!

Comment: Well, lets find out: maybe... (-_-)

Comment: @AndrewMorton maybe...

Comment: @BrandonB There is no shame in investigating it :-)

Comment: Doesn't look like it's getting eaten in the comments, did your inbox change on the second one?

Comment: @BrandonB I had other inbox items come in at just the wrong time, so it doesn't show up at all :( I reckon Matt may have supplied the reason, but perhaps someone who definitely knows will chime in.